# Radical pair mechanism in photosynthesis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, biophysics

I am aware that in Photosystem II of the chloroplast, there sometimes forms a spin-correlated radical pair of electrons whose spins precess around the effective magnetic field for several nanoseconds (see `https://www.nature.com/articles/srep08720`). My question is: is it known which two atoms the electrons in this radical pair are on? Besides this, I would like to know the quantum numbers $l$ and $m_l$ for each of the two orbitals and what other nuclei are nearby. This seems like it should be a very basic question to answer, but I have not been able to find any high-quality information online.

Comment: Based on a quick look at the introduction of the article you mentioned (and especially figure 1) I suspect that the excited electrons are at least somewhat delocalized, and also apparently move around on picosecond timescales. Thus, your "which two atoms" question may not actually be answerable as asked.

Comment: Okay, but can you at least assign quantum numbers to those electrons? Or is doing so impossible for electrons in a delocalized atomic bond?